# How do I find the Horadric Hamburger and Spectrum Blade?

Tags: diablo-iii

These two items are Whimsyshire pops and we'll assume everyone knows how to find Whimsyshire.

Are these strictly random drops within Whimsyshire or is there some method that must be followed to get them to drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are random drops from Whimsyshire.

Comment: and I think the purple boss that sometimes spawns in there has a higher chance of dropping them

Comment: Spectrum Blade is pretty frequent. I've got mine on the first run (with 200+ MF, though). From boss pony.

Comment: I have found both from Pinata's inside Whimsyshire. I'm not sure if the boss pony has a higher chance of dropping it though.